# multiple url mapping for same servlet URL produce error

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

I am trying to map multiple url pattern to same servlet and I have been writing like this.

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MyWebService</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/MyWebService</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>/ReadWebService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

from my local tomcat I was able to run without issues and I can even make calls on my local host and get the result from both urls. However, when I tried to deploy this into websphere I got the following exception

```
The following exception occured. Check log for details.
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:
[Root exception is 
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException:
    WEB-INF/web.xml]
```

I have searched this exception and did not get any useful information on what it is. Can anyone suggest why this is happening? Is my mapping wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely need to define a newer servlet version in your `web.xml`: only versions 2.5 and newer support multiple `url-pattern` in the same `servlet-mapping`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23057920/3864977

Comment: ah yes, that was the issue. I have two different version of xml